How to prevent webpack from tree shaking specific functions?
I have problem and cannot find any solution. How can i use javascript functions after bundling by webpack but in html?
I have file app.js that contains: import qs from 'query-string' (from npm install query-string) and some my code. After i run npm run dev that conatins webpack --mode production it creates another bundle file with my function and  query-string. Now i need to use it in my html code like:
<p>some text</p>
<script>
  const someConst = someFunctionFromBundle();
</script>

But after bundling webpack removes someFunctionFromBundle() because of tree shaking. How to prevent webpack from tree shaking specific functions?

Can you provide a [mcve]?

I'm battling with the same problem. Briefly, you need to configure webpack to bundle as a library. Try putting library: 'someFunctionBromBundle' in our webpack.config.js 'output' object. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library
